# Playing .exe flash file

Tags: flash, adobe-captivate

We have a .exe flash file generated from adobe captivate. If we have flash player PC,.exe will be played when we click on it. If we don't have flash player on PC,this message will come
[image: message or installing flash]
When we give ok and click on .exe file again it will be played.But in installed program list i dont see flash player.Where is flash player installed? Our problem is we dont want that message for installation. Can we do installation of flash automatically and play once we click .exe file without showing any message or can we play .exe without flash?

Comment: I guess you need to _compile_ it on newer version of Flash.

Comment: What you mean need to compile it on newer version of Flash?message says latest version installed without affecting existing flash